# Declaring a TTree Branch in PyRoot

Tags: python, root-framework, pyroot

I am trying to simply define a Root TTree using python and give it a TBranch. Sounds reasonable, right? I tried:

```
from ROOT import *
myvar = int()
mytree = TTree('mytree', 'mytree')
tree.Branch('myvar', AddressOf(myvar), 'myvar/I')
exit(0)
```

and this crashes with the error:

```
ValueError: invalid argument for AddressOf().
```

I suspected that perhaps the argument of AddressOf() needs to be a Root type like Int_t, but I didn't think python data types needed to be made explicit--and furthermore I couldn't figure out how to force the data type of of int to be Int_t. Finally, if you do the same exact thing except replace the 'int' with 'TString' and the '/I' with '/S', things do not crash. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `int` is not a c++ integer

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a different data type for "myvar".  This is because of the way the data gets used internally in root.

```
from ROOT import *
from array import array
myvar = array( 'i', [ 0 ] )
mytree = TTree('mytree', 'mytree')
mytree.Branch('myvar', myvar, 'myvar/I')
exit(0)
```

this should work and it gets rid of the crash from your example
See e.g. this web page for more information:
http://wlav.web.cern.ch/wlav/pyroot/tpytree.html

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the primary method I now use.

Answer (score 0):

A different data type may indeed be necessary, Int_t should be correct for an integer.  Take a look at the ROOT Cern Staff example with pyroot [here](https://root.cern.ch/gitweb?p=root.git;a=blob;f=tutorials/pyroot/staff.py;h=d955e2ca7481a9a507cb40dbb71c2f85ac12bbbc;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Great! This is not the prettiest solution, but I find I use it frequently now. thanks :-)